# Работа асинхронного метода

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, асинхронность

Есть следующий код на C#:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AlgorithmTools;

namespace AsyncMethods
{
    class Program
    {
        public static async void MethAsync(int num) => Console.WriteLine($"Factorial of {num} is {await FactorialAsync(num)}");

    private static Task<int> FactorialAsync(int num)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    int result = 1;

                    foreach (int i in new Range(2, num + 1))
                        result *= i;

                    return result;
                });
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethAsync(5);
    }
}
}
```

Т.к. `MethAsync` при вызове `await` на возвращаемом значении `FactorialAsync` блокируется и передает управление методу `Main`, то программа должна завершиться, не выведя значение факториала, тем не менее, оно выводится. Но если вместо `void` возвращаемым значением `MethAsync` будет `Task`, то все выполнится как надо, `Main` завершится раньше, чем посчитается факториал.
Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня, на моём компьютере ничего не выводится.

Оно и не удивительно: у вас по сути гонка между двумя событиями: окончанием программы и заданием, окончания которого вы не дожидаетесь в `Main`. Если программа завершается быстрее (как у меня), вывода не происходит. Если программа завершается медленнее (как у вас в одном из двух случаев), задание успевает завершиться, и вы видите вывод.

Перепишите программу, чтобы она дожидалась окончания задания, тогда поведение её будет детерминированным:

```
public static async Task MethAsync(int num) => ...

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await MethAsync(5);
}
```

(Кстати, вместо `Task.Factory.StartNew` имеет смысл использовать `Task.Run`.)